# How to map out Number IDs to Labels (Identifiers) in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

I want to map out number ranges into labels and have a specific cell return the label if it contains the numbers.

Let's say we have these number ranges.

3550000..3559999 | ProductA

3640000..3649999 | ProductB

5250000..5259999 | ProductC

How would I define these ranges of numbers into labels?

Then check if a specific cell contains something like, '3642515' return what product it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if A1 = 3642515

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, {3550000, ProductA; 
              3640000, ProductB; 
              5250000, ProductC}, 2, 1)
```